# Setting up kubernetes on linux raspberry

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup kubernetes cluster on raspberry pi. I have two pi, one of them will work as master and other one will work as worker.

I am not using `Hypriot Os` instead using `Raspbian stretch` image. I followed these tutorial [link1](https://blog.hypriot.com/post/setup-kubernetes-raspberry-pi-cluster/) [link2](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToBuildAKubernetesClusterWithARMRaspberryPiThenRunNETCoreOnOpenFaas.aspx). Link1 recommend to use `Hypriot Os` but I continued with `Raspbian Stretch`. This is what I have done till now on both master and worker:

1. Installed docker
2. Disabled swapfile
3. Added cgroup in /boot/cmdline.txt
4. Installed kubernetes in both the pi.
5. Initiated the master and worker then joined the master node.

Till now everything seems to working ok. But while running the command `kubectl get nodes`, I get:

```
NAME          STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
raspberrypi   NotReady   master    1h        v1.8.4
worker        NotReady   <none>    40m       v1.8.4
```

My first question is why it shows worker as `NotReady` even my worker pi is on and running.

Next question is how can I access the cluster from the its dashboard. How to install dashboard.?

Comment: hi, Can you provide the logs of kubelet ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Hi. I am now following this [tutorial](https://diffuse.cloud/2017/06/19/kubernetes-raspberry-pi/). I have followed each and every step. But at the end it shows worker as NotReady when I do kubectl get nodes. Also how can I get logs which you said. thanks

Comment: @SureshVishnoi This is the log for the dashboard `Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubernetes-dashboard" in pod "kubernetes-dashboard-7dcfc68854-slzhq" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating`

Comment: HI @Andrew, Usually you can get the logs of kubelet by using `journalctl -xeu kubelet` which works on normal linux (systemd supported OS) however you are using raspberry I am not sure which service used in this OS.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Well raspberry os is like normal linux os. I will try to execute that command. Can you tell me why it is showing my worker in NotReady status. How can I debug this.?

Comment: Kubernetes-dashboard won't be created unless and until your worker node is synched with Master node.As default we can not deploy other workloads on Master Node. So first we will debug the Worker Node then deploy other workloads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160597/discussion-between-s-andrew-and-suresh-vishnoi).

Comment: So basically Kubelet makes sure that docker engine is compatible with OS and both of them are agreed to work together,then kubelet tell Kube-Apiserver that Everything is fine at worker Node then its ready otherwise something is wrong with docker engine or node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues have been resolved in the comment section.

for debugging k8s Nodes in the cluster, we use the following command to get precise information

get the list of nodes

```
kubectl get nodes
```

get the comprehensive info

```
 kubectl describe nodes NODE_NAME
```

by the above system information, we can verify and validate the status of kubelet docker and kube-proxy

Answer (score 1):

It is showing you status as `NotReady` because you have not installed any networking driver for it. `Weave` is suitable for networking in case of Raspberry pi. You can install it by using below commands:

`kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube-1.6`

Have a look at these tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc0sbXwONM4&list=PLWw98q-Xe7iHSVH-AE9hDGBFtC9rFxcME